# Calculate and find the flux integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, spheres, stokes-theorem

Find the flux integral $$\iint_S \operatorname{rot} \vec{F} {N}\,dS$$ where $S$ is the half sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $z \ge 0$ with an aligned unit standard $\vec{N}$ (normal) and $\vec{F} =(3x-y, yz, xy)$.
I know that I should use Stokes theorem and know that rot is the same as curl and $curl \vec{F} = \nabla \times \vec{F}$ = $x-y-y+1$ but I don't know how to continue on from here.
Does working with a half sphere mean that I have 2 normals? How do I calculate the normal?
Edit: I've calculated curl: $\nabla \times F = \det \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf i& \mathbf j& \mathbf k\\\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}&\frac {\partial F}{\partial y})&\frac {\partial F}{\partial z}\\3x-y&yz&xy \end{bmatrix} = (x-y)\mathbf i  -(y\mathbf j + (1)\mathbf k$

Comment: what is rot F??

Comment: could you please specify what you mean by a 'normal'. If it is a vector then it should have an arrow on top of it

Comment: Also curl eats a vector and spits out one. So you can't just get a scalar function. If your original vector function was 3 dimensional then you need to get a 3-tuple too. Which ties in to you not being able to get a normal of a scalar. First you need a vector.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/line-integrals-in-vector-fields-articles/a/constructing-a-unit-normal-vector-to-curve#:~:text=A%20unit%20normal%20vector%20to%20a%20two%2Ddimensional%20curve%20is,curve%2C%20not%20just%20one%20vector.&text=Normalize%20the%20result%2C%20which%20requires%20dividing%20it%20by%20its%20own%20magnitude.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: What I'm trying to solve is the flux for $\iint_S curl \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N}, dS$ and I started by calculating $\nabla \times F = \det \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf i& \mathbf j& \mathbf k\\\frac {\partial F}{\partial x}&\frac {\partial F}{\partial y}&\frac {\partial F}{\partial z}\\3x-y&yz&xy \end{bmatrix} = (x-y)\mathbf i  -y\mathbf j + 1)\mathbf k$

Comment: @LordCommander It says that I have the half sphere with an aligned unit normal vector $\vec{N}$. How do I calculate the flux?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi rot should be the same as curl, I just wrote rot because that's what it said in the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux here's your answer

Comment: and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields

Comment: You can either do surface integral of the curl of the vector field or apply Stokes theorem and do line integral of the vector field on the boundary curve.

Comment: Also you wrote your working for finding curl in comments. Instead, you should provide as much details in the question as possible (not comments) otherwise it may appear to anyone reading the question that you have not put effort into it. You may get downvotes or the question may get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Stokes' theorem, $\displaystyle \iint_S (\nabla \times  \vec{F}) \cdot \hat{n} \, dS = \int_C \vec {F} \cdot dr \ $, where $C$ is the boundary curve of the surface $S$.

$S$ is $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4, z \geq 0$. Its boundary curve is circle $x^2+y^2 = 4$ at $z = 0$. Parametrize the boundary curve in polar coordinates as $r(t) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t, 0), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

$\vec{F} = (3x-y, yz, xy)$ so $\vec F(r(t)) = (6 \cos t - 2 \sin t, 0, 4 \sin t \cos t)$

Now find $r'(t)$, do the dot product and complete the line integral. That is same as the flux of $curl \vec F$ over the given hemisphere.

Comment: That actually looks pretty good, I'm just wondering why $z =0$?

Comment: Isn't half sphere in the question for $z \geq 0$ so where is the boundary of the half sphere?